# Does having both first and second violin on the same staff replace the use of div. in a symphony score?

Tags: violin, orchestra, orchestration

With consideration to the general rule that when div. is presented upper notes in the music are played by the violinist sitting on the outside, and lower notes are played by those sitting on the inside - when the music presents both first and second violin on the same staff, would this divide upper and lower notes between 1st and 2nd violin, taking place of div.?

And therefore here we are seeing these played as double stops?

Attached example[image]

Comment: Would you mind to provide the name of the piece? Note, that the full score does not necessarily indicate, what has to happen within the violin register, space saving here is top priority.

Comment: Looks like the 3rd movement of Tchaikovsky's "Pathetique" Symphony.

Comment: hello, @dekkadeci is correct! That was my initial thought - there is the possibility as this is an excerpt from a text book there may be omitted instruction.

Answer (score 3):

In a situation like this, if the stem goes up it’s V1, down for V2. E.g. bar 102 beat 2 V1 plays e-b double-stop.